# How to count the number of the generated PWM pulse on ESP32 micropython？

Tags: pwm, esp32

```
pin=Pin(17,3)
pwm=PWM(pin, freq=freq, duty=duty)
dir(pwm)  #  ['__class__', 'deinit', 'duty', 'freq', 'init']
```

How can I count it? Does micropython provide this feature?

Comment: What do you need this for? How exact does the value need to be? You can approximate the value with *#pulses = amount of time * PWM frequency*.

Comment: You can use microPython to count the High and Lows of any ESP/Rpi GPIO pin in input mode. Usually EE guys use "interrupt" input mode for the input pin. These are pretty standard stuff, so I don't think microPython bother to give your built in functions to specifically measure PWM pulses..

Comment: @StarCat I want to use pwm to control step motor. need precisely count